# How to resolve error: Command failed: powershell (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem>

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I have window 7 and I am working to add android platorm in ionicframwork so that i can build apk file.
I have correctly installed node.js then npm, then ionic cli and cordova.

Now when i move to my ionic app folder and trys to add ionic cordova platform add android. The follow error comes which you can see in below screen

Command failed: powershell (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem>.batch operable program or batch file.as as internal or external command

[Click to seen error screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRZWE.png)

How can i solve this error.

Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

add `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` to the environment variables Path